# how to split multiple columns delimited by comma in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe in which every column has 2 entries as a single unit but delimited by the comma.

```
   a         b         c               d             e
0, 162  -1.8, 162   448.25, 162     94.12, 162   4.153, 97
```

what I want is to separate them and add new columns.
I want output like

```
0   16   -1.8   162   448.25    162    94.12     162     4.153    97
```

I know the method for 1 column by adding column name but I want to know how to split multiple columns without adding column names. I don't want to write lines for each column.

Comment: How does the raw data look like? You might be able to fix it using right sep parameter while reading data into dataframe. If that is not an option, you can try something like this answer but with sep = "," https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206962/splitting-column-value-into-2-new-columns-python-pandas

Comment: raw data has a different kind of symbols and after cleaning that I am stuck here now. I know the method for 1 column but I can't do that for 28 columns separately.